# Generate an ascending order list of number in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code that imports data and stores it in the sheet. What I want is to generate a number list that is the length of the results and paste it alongside so it could be a numbered list of data.

This is what I have so far but i get the error message "Cannot find method setValues(number)." at the last row of the code.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var mv = ss.getSheetByName("Most Viewed by Country");

lr = mv.getLastRow() + 1;

for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
    var item = results.items[i];

    mv.getRange(lr,4).setValue(item.id);
    mv.getRange(lr,5).setValue(item.snippet.channelTitle)  
    mv.getRange(lr,6).setValue(item.snippet.title);
    mv.getRange(lr,7).setValue(item.statistics.viewCount);
    mv.getRange(lr,1).setValue(new Date());
    mv.getRange(lr,2).setValue('US');

    var array = new Array(results.items.length);   

    for ( var j = 1 ; j < results.items.length; j++) {
        array[j] = j 
        mv.getRange(lr, 3).setValues(j);
    }
    lr++;
}
```

Comment: Set values requires an array. Try set value.

Comment: rather than the repeated use of `getRange` and `setValue`, rewrite your approach to make the whole row, and then write the whole row. Looks like you've also erroneously included the writing of the result rank column to within the loop over the items, so you're just going to write the number of results in the same row for every result (i.e. it won't be useful.)

Comment: Each of these results I'm writing includes 50 rows of data.

Comment: @45456 so? Why would you write 50 rows cell by cell (taking 0.2 seconds each) when you can write 50 rows in sets of 50 rows (and in less than a second, total!)? Review my answer and apply what you learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

To write data efficiently, you want to use [`setValues(obj)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) with an `obj` that is an `Array` of `Array`s, where each inner `Array` is the same size (i.e. `obj` is a rectangular 2D Array). Given that you have the results at the start, you can simply write once after doing all manipulation and prep within a [JavaScript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

As an example:

```
function writeResults(sheet, results) {
  if (!sheet) throw new Error("Need a Sheet object to write to");
  if (!results || !results.items || !results.items.length) throw new Error("Need results to print");
  // Initialize the output array (and the data headers as the first row).
  const output = [
    ["TimeStamp", "Region", "Rank", "Item ID"]
  ];
  const now = new Date();

  // Add all the items in our result to the output. We assume result.items is
  // already sorted such that the first item has the best rank, and that there are no ties.
  results.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var row = [];

    row.push(now);
    row.push("US");
    row.push(1 + index);
    row.push(item.id);

    output.push(row);
  });

  // Erase everything already on the sheet.
  sheet.getDataRange().clear();
  // Ensure the erase is prior to the write.
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  // Write the new data into A1:D<N>
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

Obviously you probably want to add more columns to the output, and you might not want to erase the existing data on the given sheet (preferring instead to write into the next open row), but you should be able to handle those minor modifications, especially since you have existing code that already finds the start of that Range. The point of this answer is to guide you in manipulating JavaScript Arrays, not do all your work for you :)

Working in this manner - using batch methods `Range#getValues()` and `Range#setValues()` - is an [**Apps Script "best practice"**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) and will ensure you have timely code that does not overrun your daily execution time quota (very important for time-based trigger functions).

References:

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Range#setValues(obj)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [`Sheet#getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: This works perfectly and I changed the code so it adds the data to the end of the results instead of replacing it. The only issue is the,
const output = [ ["TimeStamp", "Region", "Rank", "Item ID"]  ];

I don't want the header row repeated everytime the data is updated. is there a way to define a "const" without the header labels?

Comment: @45456 ? it's just an array with a value in it. If you don't want it to start with a value, don't start it with a value.

Comment: no it's impoting 50 rows of data from Youtube API. The data updates daily. So with this method each time the data updates the header gets inserted in the middle of the sheet. I have entered the header manually and I just want the data to be generated by script.

Comment: @45456 `const` in JavaScript means "constant reference". It does not mean the object is immutable - this is already clear, since we modify properties of `output` in the loop. What I meant earlier is: you are the programmer - you do more than just run code. If you want to make the variable labeled "output" be something else, you just write different code. If you wanted to initialize it with thirty rows of headers, you could. If you wanted to have it be a regular object reference, one which supports reference reassignment, you could. If you wanted it to be named "SusieQ", you could.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Thanks for all the help

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var mv = ss.getSheetByName("Most Viewed by Country");
lr = mv.getLastRow() + 1;
for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    mv.getRange(lr+i,4).setValue(item.id);
    mv.getRange(lr+i,5).setValue(item.snippet.channelTitle)  
    mv.getRange(lr+i,6).setValue(item.snippet.title);
    mv.getRange(lr+i,7).setValue(item.statistics.viewCount);
    mv.getRange(lr+i,1).setValue(new Date());
    mv.getRange(lr+i,2).setValue('US');
    mv.getRange(lr+i,3).setValue(i+1);
}
```